# B1/B2 Visa Error

Tags: visas, b1-b2-visas, tourist-visas

I accidentally put B1/B2 as my visa option even if I'm just going to the US for a graduation ceremony. I thought B2 was just for medical purpose. I already booked an interview. What should I do?

Comment: It’s fine. What’s the error?

Comment: Even if you put B-2, they would probably have given you a B-1/B-2 visa anyway (I think the likelihood depends on your country of citizenship, however).  There are anecdotes here of people making slight category changes like this in the interview.  Even if you have a B-1/B-2 visa, when you enter the US you will be admitted either in B-1 or B-2 status, so the difference between a B-2 visa and B-1/B-2 is quite limited, and there's essentially no difference if you never visit for business.  It shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 4):

There's no error. All B-2 visas are tourist visitor visas, the type of visa you'd use to attend a graduation ceremony (they're used for medical visits as well). So you should go to your interview as planned.

In most cases, the US will actually issue a B-1/B-2 visa, which can be used for both business (B-1) and tourism (B-2).